# How to view files a php application deployed to google app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have deployed a php application to google app engine. I can access the application using the url: http://project-id.appspot.com. Since, I have integrated log4php in my application, I want to access the log files of the application using putty or winscp(sftp). How can I access the files deployed on the server ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at ["Reading and Writing Application Logs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/logs/). If you log in the correct manner, logs are viewable in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) or by using the [`gcloud app logs read`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/logs/read) command.

Comment: What about SFTP access to files which have been deployed. Can't we use SFTP to view files? How can I view log files using cloud shell ?

Comment: You can download the deployed application files. See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/tools/downloading-source-code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can use Logs PHP API to write and read logs. But I chose to configure log4php to log into the database.

Thanks